# When does Powershell honour default values when using $null splat parameters?

Tags: powershell, parameters, null, default, scriptblock

Consider the following function:

```
function f1{
    param(
        $sb = {},
        $s  = ''
    )
    if ($sb -isnot [scriptblock]) { 'scriptblock' }
    if ($s  -isnot [string]     ) { 'string' }
}
```

Now invoke it with a splat parameter:

```
PS C:\> $splat = @{foo='bar'}
PS C:\> f1 @splat
```

As expected, nothing is returned.  Now try it again with a `$null` splat parameter:

```
PS C:\> $splat = $null
PS C:\> f1 @splat
scriptblock
```

Oddly, `scriptblock` is returned.  Clearly, at least for the `[scriptblock]` parameter, powershell is not honoring the default value when a `$null` splat parameter is used.  But powershell does honor the default value for the `[string]`.  What is going on here?

For what types does Powershell honour default values when using $null splat parameters?

Comment: I don't think its the type, its the order of the parameters. When you try to splat a null powershell is just passing it as the first parameter. Then the second parameter gets its default value.

Comment: It looks like you're correct.  Switching the parameters yields `string` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Isn't this just normal application of positional parameters? You are splatting a single `$null` which is being applied to `$sb`.

Compare:

```
> function f{ param($sb = {}, $s = '') $PSBoundParameters }
> $splat = @(1,2)
> f @splat
Key                                                 Value
---                                                 -----
sb                                                      1
s                                                       2
> f @flkejlkfja
Key                                                 Value
---                                                 -----
sb
> function f{ param($aaa = 5, $sb = {}, $s = '') $PSBoundParameters }
> f @splat
Key                                                 Value
---                                                 -----
aaa                                                 1
sb                                                  2
```

Answer (score 2):

It's an old question but if it is still interesting...

As others have written with `$splat = $null` calling `f1 @splat` the first parameters will get the value `$null` instead it's default value.

If you want the parameters use their default value in this case you have to use `$splat = @{}` or `$splat = @()`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a demonstration to help understand what's happening

```
$splat = @{foo='bar'}
"$(&{$args}@splat)"
-foo: bar
```

When you splat the hash table, it gets converted to -Key: Value string pairs that become the parameters to your function.

Now try:

```
$splat = $null
"$(&{$args}@splat)"
```

Nothing is returned.  There are no keys to generate the parameter string from, so the end result is the same as not passing any parameters at all.

Comment: Thanks!  This makes what's happening much more clear.

Comment: A value _is_ being passed when you splat `$null`: `$splat = $null; & { $Args.count } @splat` yields `1`. The value being passed is `$null`, which makes no effective difference with `$Args`, but does matter with declared parameters, as in the OP's case.

Answer (score 1):

To complement [Etan Reisner's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29088346/45375) with a more direct demonstration that **splatting `$null` indeed passes `$null` as the *first* (and only) *positional* argument**:

```
$splat = $null
& { [CmdletBinding(PositionalBinding=$False)] param($dummy) } @splat
```

The above yields the following *error*:

```
A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '$null'.
...
```

Decorating the `param()` block with `[CmdletBinding(PositionalBinding=$False)]` ensures that only *named* parameter values can be passed, causing the *positional* passing of `$null` from splatting to trigger the error above.

Note that using the special "null collection" value (`[System.Management.Automation.Internal.AutomationNull]::Value`) that you get from commands that produce no output for splatting is effectively the same as splatting `$null`, because that "null collection" value is converted to `$null` during parameter binding.

---

[VargaJoe's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49958928/45375) explains how to construct a variable for splatting so that *no* arguments are passed, so that the callee's default parameter values are honored.